# 10.10 Freezes totally

Tags: 10.10, freeze

My Maverick freezes constantly, no matter what I'm doing. Browsing with chromium or firefox, using cmus to play music, or copying 24 gb files from partition to partition while burning a CD, it will freeze, and only thing I can do is unplug it from the grid, no button will work.

Extra information:

- [kern.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/543142/)
- [dmesg output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/543143/)

Any help appreciated! If it's hardware, so I can know what to do and what to backup :)

Command "sensors" says:

acpitz-virtual-0

Adapter: Virtual device

temp1:       +40.0°C  (crit = +95.0°C)

k8temp-pci-00c3

Adapter: PCI adapter

Core0 Temp:  +24.0°C
Core1 Temp:  +24.0°C

Comment: Plase check /var/log/kern.log for any errors that might be related to the freeze, also please note that on hard freezes most PCs can be powered off with the power button by just keeping the button pressed for 5 seconds.

Comment: can you give us some information about the system's hardware?

Comment: Also try to perform a memtest to check your RAM (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that there is a serious bug in **libgobject**. If you search for "segfault", you will see that just after nautilus crashes the machine stops and after few lines, time starts at 0 again as you reset your machine.

> nautilus[1634]: segfault at 20 ip 004dfddf sp bfeb2ab0 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.2600.0[4b3000+40000]
>
> Dec 12 19:33:29 Hyperion kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.

You should report a bug with command **ubuntu-bug ubuntu-desktop** and include kern.log in the report.

Comment: Bug reported. Will reinstall fix the problem, since i can't do pretty much anything ?

Comment: If the problem began after last update, then you can lock/prevent libgobject from updating after fresh install to the latest version. How to do this look here http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/09/block-program-package-future-upgrades-ubuntu-10-0410-10-maverick-meerkat/

Comment: Seems like any major hard disk interaction will freeze my system. That means that transmission verifying torrent data = freeze; using wine to "install" deus ex = freeze; using midnight commander to copy about 700 mb of data = freeze... Now im puzzled

Comment: This libgobject file is part of libglib library which is very common. If you don't want to risk reinstalling and upgrading to same problem, then try few hours with live session from install cd to confirm my theory. I just checked, wine does not use libgobject so it is a bit weird, it could be a background operation from gnome that caused the freeze though.

Comment: Reinstalation did the trick, for now :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with every hard disk that I plugged to my motherboard Asrock 939A8X-M. When the disk was intensively used the system was frozen and a black screen with the mouse pointer is usually obtained.
This problem happened using Lucid and Maverick  **but not using Karmic, with  2.6.31-22 kernel (32 or 64 bits) for instance**, then I donwgraded the whole system to karmic and from this I am working happy without problems.
The freeze happened to my using PATA disks or SATA, it doesn't matter which kind or brand of hard disks. It seems to be a bug in the new kernels after 2.6.32 with the Asrock 939A8X-M. My processor is an ADM X2 4200+, and the bug was in 32 and in 64 bits.
With bests regards.